# How to correctly catch errors in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given the example that you are connecting to a mongoDB in js.

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb:/localhost/db", 
function (err, db){
    if (err){
       throw err   
    }
} // some following code
```

What is the correct to catch errors in an express application so the program carries on running? Currently I have it set up as an if/else. Which does do the trick, it keeps the program running. But it seems a bad way to do it.

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb:/localhost/db", 
function (err, db){
    if (err){
       resp.json(err)
       console.log(err)
    } else {
       // some following code 
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to catch errors?

Comment: Should the application really keep running after the connection to the database has failed? In any case, better use a library that supports promises, then use the `promise.then().catch()` flow

Comment: We would have to see the calling context and you would have to say what you think is a proper and good behavior when there is an error (usually it's to communicate back an error to the caller).  `throw err` in an async callback is pretty  much never the right answer as that is usually just lost in some async callback with no ability for anyone to actually handle the error and do something intelligent with it.

Comment: The error handling just returns in a resp.json and console.log(//logging purposes). But is an if/else statement okay for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

```
new Error([message[, fileName[, lineNumber]]])
```

this format won't break your server.
but, in case of DATABASE connection errors, server will still not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

use this in server.js or main.js or app.js file it handle all errors and send you error with status code

```
 app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
   console.error(err)
   return res.status(500).send({err:err})
 });

 mongoClient.connect("mongodb:/localhost/db", function (err, db, next){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      return next(err);
    } else {
      // some following code 
    }
 }
```